# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, can't get the value of first_child

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

im trying to get the value from the first child of the 'td' element, in this case its the "Lorem ipsum odd" or "Lorem ipsum even" using PHP Simple html dom parser. 
I tried to read the manual but I just got more confused.
Thanks for help.

here's my html

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>
                Lorem ipsum odd
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">odd</a>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>
                lorem ipsum 
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">even</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>
                Lorem ipsum odd
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">odd</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>
                Lorem ipsum even
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">even</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here's my php,

```
    <?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('myfile.html');

$h = $html->find('table');
foreach($h as $element){
    foreach ($element->find('.odd, .even') as $td) {
        foreach ($td->first_child() as $key) {
            echo $key->plaintext;
        }
    }
}



?>
```

link to PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Comment: are you getting any results? any errors?

Comment: Result = "Lorem ipsum odd oddlorem ipsum evenLorem ipsum odd oddLorem ipsum even evenLorem ipsum odd oddLorem ipsum even evenLorem ipsum odd oddLorem ipsum even evenLorem ipsum odd odd" and no errors

Comment: I want the result "Lorem ipsum odd, lorem ipsum even", not "Lorem ipsum odd odd, lorem ipsum even even"

Comment: It seems to be running through all children to be doing that, I would try replacing foreach ($td->first_child() as $key) {echo $key->plaintext; } with  echo $td->first_child()->plaintext;

Comment: ty, it works! :D

Comment: no worries, glad I could help